# fork() in c using printf

Tags: c, fork, printf

There are 2 different programs, they are small for example:

```
int main()
{
        printf ("print hello");
        fork();
}
```

---

```
int main()
{
        printf ("print hello\n");
        fork();
}
```

output 1 is: `print helloprint hello

output 2 is:`print hello`

The question is, why does the one with the `\n` only print once, and the first one prints it twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running into the buffering behaviour of your system's `printf` implementation.  In the first case, the string is printed to a buffer, but since there's no newline (and you didn't call `fflush`), it's just sitting there in that buffer.  Then you fork, and both forked buffers are flushed when their respective processes exit.

In the second case, the `\n` causes the buffer to be flushed *before* the fork, so there's no output remaining when the forked processes exit.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
    printf ("print hello");
    fork();
```

to

```
    printf ("print hello");
    fflush(stdout);
    fork();
```

By default, `stdout` is usually line-buffered. In your example 2) you have the guarantee that `stdout` is flushed before the `fork` but in the example 1) it may happen after the `fork`. Flushing `stdout` before the `fork` guarantee you to have the string printed before the `fork`.

Comment: this really doesn't answer "why"