# Questions on fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am trying to understand fork(), and so I put together the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
   if(fork()==0)
   {
      printf("2");

      if(fork()==0)
      {
          printf("4");
      }
      else
      {
          printf("3");
      }
   } 
   else
   {
      printf("1");
   }
}
```

When I was tracing this on paper, I drew the following sketch:

[image]

So I believe the output should be *1234.* However, when I run this code, the output is **12324**. *Why is that? Where is my mistake?*

### Update:

After reading the comments, it was suggested to do any of the following

1. Add **`\n`** to each *printf* statement
2. OR: Add **`fflush(stdout);`** after each *printf* statement
3. OR: Add **`setbuf(stdout, NULL);`**   <---- this is what I ended-up doing :)

After updating my code, the output was indeed *1234.*

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454610/fork-in-c-using-printf, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581787/why-does-this-code-print-two-times, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513242/working-of-fork-in-linux-gcc and some more ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`printf()` output is usually line-buffered. So when you `fork()`, the new processes gets the copy of the buffer as well. When the process exits, the whole buffer is flushed (or anytime it's flushed in the code or whenever the buffer becomes full). Hence, you see a *copy* of `printf`'s output one more time.

1) You can flush it after each `printf()` call by using `fflush(stdout);`

2) or using `\n` for example:

```
  printf("2\n");
```

---

Another way is to disable the buffering with:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Comment: I think you meant `fflush(stdout)`?

Answer (score 6):

Your analysis is almost correct. However, `printf` does not necessarily write immediately do file descriptor - output is buffered inside the process. The second process does `fork` after putting `2` in the buffer. Both second and third processes will have it in the buffer and print `2`.

If you do `printf("2\n")` instead new line character will force `printf` to flush the buffer and you will see only one `2`.

Comment: Alright, let me add \n