# Difference in Output between printf("\n...") and printf("..\n") in Linux

Tags: c, linux, printf

Can somebody explain to me why these two similar codes (except for the `\n` position) result in different output:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int pid, i=0;
    printf("Ready to fork\n");
    pid=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    {
        printf("Child starts\n");
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++);
        printf("Child ends\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wait(0);
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++);
        printf("Parent process ends\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

[image]

And this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int pid, i=0;
    printf("\nReady to fork %d", getpid());
    pid=fork();
    if (pid==0)
    {
        printf("\nChild starts %d",getpid());
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++);
        printf("\nChild ends %d", getpid());
    }
    else
    {
        wait(0);
        for (i=0; i<1000; i++);
        printf("\nParent process ends %d", getpid());
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Results in:

[image]

I really can’t find any satisfactory reason of why a simple change in the position of `\n` changes the output of the program at the level where the parent program seems to restart after fork execution completes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could format your code, so that others read it. And also, the `'\n'` is usually at the end. There is no change in the output.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: What do you mean there is no change in the output? The entire question asks why there **is** a change in the output. And it shows changed output.

Comment: I'm not going to read that unformatted code, but probably duplicate of [fork() in c using printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17454610/995714)

Comment: I see it now, I just didn't note it at first.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yea, duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the program's output is redirected to a file, `printf()`ing `\n` results, by default, in *flushing* the *user-space buffer* that `printf()` internally uses.

Not flushing the buffer before `fork()` implies that the child process obtains a copy of the parent's process not-yet-flushed buffer. For that reason you see `Ready to fork` twice in the version that is not printing `\n`, since the call to `printf()` for printing `Ready to fork` is performed before the call to `fork()`.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you very much.

Comment: A tiny bit of confusion... Is it the child gets the buffer data, or when the control returns to caller and finds "\n" it flushes the buffer ?

Comment: The child always get a copy of the parent's buffer by `fork()`ing. The question is: Is this buffer empty or not? Well, if the buffer is flushed before the call to `fork()` it will be empty for sure. By calling `printf()` with a trailing `\n` the buffer is flushed (unless output is redirected or flushing policy is changed). The parent is doing so in your 1st case.

Comment: Note that after the `fork()` both buffers (parent and child) are independent (i.e.: each process has its own copy), but it is at the moment of forking when the child gets a copy of the parent's buffer (i.e.: the child's buffer is initialized with the content of the parent's buffer at that moment).